# Tikz in RMarkdown

Tags: tikz-pgf, rmarkdown

I have a diagram rendered using tikz and would like to include it at multiple places throughout my document. I have tried to define a command to insert this into the `tikz` environment, however I'm not very familiar with `LaTeX` and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
\newcommand\ThreeStateDiagram{}
\def\ThreeStateDiagram{
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      sharp corners=2pt,
      inner sep=7pt,
      node distance=3cm,
      >=latex]
  \tikzstyle{my node}=[draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm]
  \node[my node] (A){A};
  \node[my node,right of=A](C){C};
  \node[my node] at ($(A)!0.5!(C)-(0pt,1.5cm)$) (B) {B};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
  \draw[->] (A) -- (C);
  \draw[->] (B) -- (C);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

An added bit of difficulty is that I'm writing my document in RMarkdown and using the built-in `tikz` engine to render it. Here is the code in `RMarkdown`:

````
```{tikz, ThreeStateDiagram, fig.cap="Layout Diagram", fig.align="center"}
\ThreeStateDiagram;
`` `
````

And I can then use `\@ref(tab:ThreeStateDiagram)` to cross-reference it (because I'm using `{bookdown}`).

For clarity, the below works fine (in LaTeX, HTML and Word formats), however I don't want to have to insert this (with different captions) repeatedly:

````
```{tikz, ThreeStateDiagram, fig.cap="Layout of the MSM used in the motivating model", fig.align="center"}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      sharp corners=2pt,
      inner sep=7pt,
      node distance=3cm,
      >=latex]
  \tikzstyle{my node}=[draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm]
  \node[my node] (A){A};
  \node[my node,right of=A](C){C};
  \node[my node] at ($(A)!0.5!(C)-(0pt,1.5cm)$) (B) {B};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
  \draw[->] (A) -- (C);
  \draw[->] (B) -- (C);
  \end{tikzpicture}
`` `
````

Comment: "It doesn't seem to be working"... well, maybe, but what does it complain about? Loading tikZ libraries has to take place ONCE, in the document header. That may be it. Furthermore, it's strange to see you define your command twice, first using LaTeX's `\newcommand` with no content and then switching back to TeX's mor basic `\def`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. As @ChristophFrings said you seem to have a couple of problems with your document. This is only by looking at a couple of code snippets. It would make it far easier for us to figure out all the problems if you give us a small document that recreates the problem starting with `\documentclass{` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

`knitr`'s `tikz` engine renders the figure into a pdf file and then includes it via

```
\begin{figure}
...
\includegraphics{[path-to-pdf-figure]}
...
\end{figure}
```

which you can check yourself if your specify `keep_tex: true` in your YAML header output section and examine the resulting *.tex file (`_book/_main.tex` by default).

If you have named the respective chunk, e.g. as `ThreeStateDiagram` then the figure is named ThreeStateDiagram-1.pdf

If you are using the `bookdown` package to manage and render your document, then the figure is stored in `_bookdown_files/_main_files/figure_latex/ThreeStateDiagram-1.pdf`

If the respective chunk is the nth unnamed chunk, then the figure's filename  is `unnamed-chunk-[n]-1.pdf` (replace `n` with the actual value) and will be residing in the same directory as mentioned above.

In case your `documentclass` is `beamer` or you specified  `output: bookdown::beamer_presentation2` in your `_output.yml`, then the path is `_bookdown_files/_main_files/figure_beamer/foo-1.pdf`

Hence you can reuse the figure in subsequent code in a similar fashion.