# Tikz `regular polygon` in Rmarkdown

Tags: tikz-styles, rmarkdown

I am looking to produce a tikz figure with a node triangle. Most ressources I have found online use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` and its `regular polygon`. Rmarkdown seems unable to use it.

This will work in overleaf :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, circle,minimum size=1cm,thick] (cir) at (0,0) {Test};
\node [draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1cm,thick] (tri) at (0, -2) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

but not in Rmarkdown.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "My name"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{tikz}
  - \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
---

```{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, circle,minimum size=1cm,thick] (cir) at (0,0) {Test};
\node [draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1cm,thick] (tri) at (0, -2) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

I received this error.

```
processing file: tests.Rmd

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/regular polygon' and I am
 going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Quitting from lines 11-15 (tests.Rmd) 
Erreur : LaTeX failed to compile tikz2b045722257b.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See tikz2b045722257b.log for more info.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Long time lurker, first time poster! @Mensch

Comment: Have you tried `shapes.geometric` instead of `shapes`?

Comment: Yes, but it did not worked. I have found out that you can call \usetikzlibrary{shapes} in the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576790/tikz-in-rmarkdown?rq=1), I have tried to write `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` in the `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `\end{tikzpicture}` and it worked!

Here is the solution:

```
title: "Untitled"
author: "My name"
output: pdf_document


{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\node [draw, circle,minimum size=1cm,thick] (cir) at (0,0) {Test};
\node [draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1cm,thick] (tri) at (0, -2) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```